# Registering types with lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, unity-container

I was wondering how do I achieve such a feature in the UnityContainer:

```
container.RegisterType<IDummy>(Func<IDummy>) // deferred resolution
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're going to register factory instead of instance, try this:

```
container.RegisterType<IDummy>(new InjectionFactory(context => new Dummy()));
```

Just replace "context => new Dummy()" with your lambda.

Comment: This method is obsolete. Current way of doing this : container.RegisterFactory<IDummy>(context => new Dummy());