# IDbConnection in instance field and using clause

Tags: c#, wpf, oop

I am writing a service class doing some interaction with an underlying database. I am passing the connection as a parameter in the class constructor.

```
public class MyDbService : IDbService
{
    private readonly IDbConnection _connection;

    public MyDbService(IDbConnection connection)
    {
        _connection = connection;
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        // Sql-Server implementation
        var conn = _connection as SqlConnection;
        if(conn != null)
        {
            using(conn)
            {
                conn.Open();
                // Do stuff
            }
        }

        // Implementation for other providers
        ...
    }
}
```

`DoStuff()` is working the first time it is called, but due to the `using()` clause, the conn object is disposed and i get an `InvalidOperationException` when `conn.Open()` is called again.

I can get around the problem by removing the `using` and put a `conn.Close()`, but that seems like an "ugly" choice to me?

So, I have two questions, the first being quite fundamental to oop:

1. Why is the `_connection` object being disposed when I use `using(conn)`?
2. What is "best practice" when it comes to passing connection objects in the constructor?

EDIT:

The class is part of a WPF application.

Since the problem seems to be connected with DI, I have outlined the classes behind. I get, that I need to pass in a fresh instance of the connection object, since it gets disposed after the first use in the service - I just can't see how (at least not without carrying though the Unity container to the viewmodel and manually resolve). Of course a very easy solution is to pass the connection string and provider to the service constructor instead, but i would like to get this approach to work somehow. Any hints are greatly appreciated :)

App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            var connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalTest"].ConnectionString;
            var providerName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalTest"].ProviderName;

            var connection = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName).CreateConnection();

            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = connString;
                var myService= new MyDbService(connection);

                // Register dependency injection
                var container = new UnityContainer();
                container.RegisterInstance<IDbConnection>(connection);
                container.RegisterInstance<IDbService>(myService);


                var mainWindow = container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
                mainWindow.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle null connection
            }
        }
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow: Window
{
    private MyViewModel _vm;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [Dependency]
    public MyViewModel ViewModel
    {
        set
        {
            _vm = value;
            DataContext = _vm;
        }
    }
}
```

MyViewModel.cs:

```
public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly IDbService _dbService;

    public MyViewModel(IDbService dbService)
    {
        _dbService = dbService;
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        _dbService.DoStuff();
    }

    ...

    // Other viewmodel stuff

}
```

Comment: Does you connection create with `Singleton()` lifecycle?

Comment: I create the connection like this: `var connection =      DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName).CreateConnection()` and pass it in via Unity DI

Comment: Are you sure, that each time you pass IDbConnection- it's new connection? When you call `DoStuff()` second time, looks like you pass here IDbConnection from the first time, that have been already disposed.

Answer (score 0):

The `_connection` is being disposed because you are wrapping it in a `using` statement and you may be passing the same instance in each time because it looks like you create a connection `var connection = ...` and then pass that same variable each time via DI. Then in the `DoStuff` method it gets disposed, but then the same disposed instance is being passed into the next `MyDbService`.

When you setup your DI instead of returning a single variable, i.e. `connection`, try returning `DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName).CreateConnection()`. This way each time a new `IDbConnection` is requested from your DI container you will always get a new database instance.

I've not used Unity before, but you should change `container.RegisterInstance<IDbConnection>(connection);` to use a version of the `Register` method that accepts a lambda expression, for example:

`container.Register<IDbConnection>(c => DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName).CreateConnection);`

The following post uses `InjectionFactory` and may provide a useful example on how to do this: [Registering types with lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256940/registering-types-with-lambda-expression).

UPDATE #1: As a side note I wouldn't dispose of the connection is `DoStuff`. Instead implement `IDisposable` and dispose of `_connection` in there. This then allows you to reuse the connection in other methods of the class.

UPDATE #2: I would also do your `_connection as SqlConnection` in your constructor and then store a reference in `_connection`. If the cast fails, then throw an exception. This ensures you have a valid connection type before the caller goes on to use the methods/properties of the class. You can then remove the cast from your `DoStuff` method.

Comment: Thank you both of you. Based on your comments, I realize that i might have an issue with injecting the connection correctly. I will try to work on that and update the post.